# what is the value of AUTHORITY to delete messages

Tags: android, android-contentprovider

Good day to all!!!

We can delete call history using `CallLog.AUTHORITY`. Here is an utility method to delete calls...

```
public static void deleteCallLogsFromNative(Context context, long[] rowIds) {
    ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation> operations = new ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation>(
            rowIds.length);
    for (int i = 0, N = rowIds.length; i < N; i++) {
        operations.add(ContentProviderOperation
                .newDelete(CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI)
                .withSelection(CallLog.Calls._ID + " = ?",
                        new String[] { String.valueOf(rowIds[i]) }).build());
    }
    try {
        context.getContentResolver().applyBatch(CallLog.AUTHORITY,
                operations);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG,
                "Error while deleting calls from native: " + e.toString());
    }
}
```

You can observe that for applying batch operation, we need an AUTHORITY and here is `CallLog.AUTHORITY` is required to delete call logs.

Similarly I have another utility method for deleting messages...

```
public static void deleteMessagesFromNative(Context context, long[] rowIds) {
    ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation> operations = new ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation>(
            rowIds.length);
    for (int i = 0, N = rowIds.length; i < N; i++) {
        long rowId = rowIds[i];
        operations.add(ContentProviderOperation
                .newDelete(Uri.parse("content://sms/"))
                .withSelection(BaseColumns._ID + " = ?",
                        new String[] { String.valueOf(rowId) }).build());
    }
    try {
       // here I need AUTHORITY value for deleting messages
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
    }
}
```

Now my question is, What is the value of `AUTHORITY` to delete messages?